# Implementing banker's rounding for integer division

Tags: c, embedded, rounding, integer-division, bankers-rounding

What would be the simplest formula to implement `int divround(int a, int b) {...}`, in C, where output is a/b with banker's rounding (round half to even)?

For example, `divround(3,2)` and `divround(5,2)` both evaluate to 2.

I'm writing embedded code, so I cannot rely on libraries. I want the code to be generic for ARM and RISC-V, so no assembly as well. I'm trying to mimick the behavior of `np.around(a/b)` in NumPy (which performs round half to even), so I can exactly compare output test vectors from Python and my embedded application.

Comment: @klutt yes halves are possible to represent exactly in normal floating point.  The question is about integers anyway so I don't see how your comment is relevant.

Comment: sorry, edited the question to clarify. need to implement `int divround(int a, int b) {...}`

Comment: Sometimes the OP is flamed for not providing code... and sometimes SO provides the absent code. Makes one wonder....

Comment: @Fe2O3 It's almost as if the users are different people with their own judgment.

Comment: Can't you just use (2a+b)/(2b)? You'll have to check for overflows of course.

Comment: @SimonGoater No, "banker's rounding" rounds an exact half towards the nearest even number.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `a` and `b` are nonnegative, and `b` is less than `INT_MAX / 2`, the following is a simple implementation:

```
int divround(int a, int b)
{
    int q = a / b;
    int r = a % b;

    if (2*r > b) {
        return q + 1;
    } else if (2*r < b) {
        return q;
    } else if (q % 2 == 0) {
        return q;
    } else {
        return q + 1;
    }
}
```

For an explanation:

- If the remainder of division is more than half of `b` round up and if it's less round down.
- If the remainder is `b/2` exactly, then check if the quotient is even, and if so round down otherwise round up.

If you also want to handle negative values, first determine the sign of the result and normalize the values to nonnegative, then perform the above while multiplying the sign to the result.  Works assuming `b` is between `INT_MIN / 2` and `INT_MAX / 2`.

```
int divround(int a, int b)
{
    int s_a = 1, s_b = 1;

    if (a < 0) {
        a = -a;
        s_a = -1;
    }
    if (b < 0) {
        b = -b;
        s_b = -1;
    }

    int q = a / b;
    int r = a % b;
    int sign = s_a * s_b;

    if (2*r > b) {
        return sign * (q + 1);
    } else if (2*r < b) {
        return sign * q;
    } else if (q % 2 == 0) {
        return sign * q;
    } else {
        return sign * (q + 1);
    }
}
```

And of course, don't divide by 0.

Comment: Can you remove the `b < INT_MAX / 2` restriction?  If `b` is that big, the answer will be zero, won't it?  Are there similar constraints for large negative divisors?

Comment: Branchless: `int q = a / b;  int r = a % b * 2;  return q + ( (r==b)*(q%2) + (r>b) );` `:-)`

Comment: Don't really need variables `s_a` and `s_b`. `int sign = 1;` then replace `s_a = -1;` with `sign = -sign;`, and same for `s_b = -1;`... Then get rid of `sign = s_a * s_b`... Less code is better code, imho...

Comment: @Fe2O3: You could post that as an answer.  It's probably more efficient than the other answers, at least on high-end CPUs where branch mispredicts are expensive.  (Still only one `idiv` on x86-64, using both quotient and remainder, and no branching, and a reasonable amount of later instructions.)  https://godbolt.org/z/oM8EjePvj - but note that clang re-invents the branch when compiling your boolean multiply for some ISAs (like ARM and x86-64, but not AArch64 where `csel` and `cinc` (conditional increment) are perfect for the job.

Comment: @PeterCordes Shortly after I started visiting SO, I posted a solution to a question that involved branchless code. (Yes, I was _flippant_ in the answer.) The ruckus that caused has me reluctant to again raise my head high in that regard.) Here, dbush remains silent regarding even the 2nd suggestion about using fewer variables... So it goes...

Comment: @Fe2O3: If you posted a readable answer with that branchless version of dbush's code, I'd upvote it.  (Especially if you pointed out any advantage of that in this case, like how it compiles quite efficiently for AArch64.) I don't always agree that less code is better code, though; sometimes more code helps show the steps and makes room to explain each one separately in comments or with meaningful variable names. `q + ( (r==b)*(q%2) + (r>b) );` is what some people would call "write-only code", that after writing it, it's hard to see *why* it should be that way a year later, or for other humans.

Comment: @njuffa For the non-negative implementation, b < INT_MAX/2 is fine.  For the version handling negatives, it's INT_MIN/2 < b < INT_MAX/2.  I've updated to note that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a branchless version of @dbush's answer (with test cases), which handles positive or negative `a` and `b`.  If you only have non-negative `a` and positive `b`, remove the `sign` handling part.  (Or make that part branchy if negative inputs are rare for most uses.)

This has the same limitations as dbush's version, specifically that `INT_MIN/2 < b < INT_MAX/2` (or thereabouts) is required.  This is fewer instructions on ARM with clang or GCC than @njuffa's fully general-case version, but still quite a few total to handle the signs as well as the rounding.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int divround( int a, int b ) {
    printf( "%3d / %2d", a, b );
    int sign = ((a<0)^(b<0))*-2+1; // if 'a' and 'b' opposite signs then -1, else 1

  // This can have signed overflow; making both negative also works, see below
    a = a<0 ? -a : a;    // abs(a)
    b = b<0 ? -b : b;    // abs(b)

    int q = a / b; // quotient (will be +'ve)
    int r = a % b * 2; // remainder ... doubled!!
    return sign * ( q + (r==b)*(q%2) + (r>b) ); // see comments below...
}

int main( void ) {
    typedef int P[2];
    P arr[] = { { 12, 4 }, { 13, 4 }, { 14, 4 }, { 15, 4 } };

    for( P *p = arr; p < arr + sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]; p++ ) {
        printf( " = %d\n",   divround( +(*p)[0], +(*p)[1] ) );
        printf( " = %d\n",   divround( +(*p)[0], -(*p)[1] ) );
        printf( " = %d\n",   divround( -(*p)[0], +(*p)[1] ) );
        printf( " = %d\n\n", divround( -(*p)[0], -(*p)[1] ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 12 /  4 = 3
 12 / -4 = -3
-12 /  4 = -3
-12 / -4 = 3

 13 /  4 = 3
 13 / -4 = -3
-13 /  4 = -3
-13 / -4 = 3

 14 /  4 = 4
 14 / -4 = -4
-14 /  4 = -4
-14 / -4 = 4

 15 /  4 = 4
 15 / -4 = -4
-15 /  4 = -4
-15 / -4 = 4
```

Concerning `return sign * ( q + (r==b)*(q%2) + (r>b) );`

1. Multiplying computed quotient by `sign` restoring possible negative.
2. 'q' is the calculated (integer division) quotient (that will be +'ve).
3. `(r==b)*(q%2)` If 2xRemainder `r` equals divisor, then this is exactly 0.5 remainder.
   Add 1 to `q`, but only if `q` is odd.
4. *Otherwise*, add 1 to `q` when 2xRemainder is GT the divisor.

---

Concerned about trying to change `INT_MIN` to a +'ve value? The following changes work around that problem. Instead of dividing +'ve numbers, divide -'ve numbers instead...

```
    a = a*(a<0) + -a*(a>=0); // if 'a' +'ve, then make -'ve
    b = b*(b<0) + -b*(b>=0); // same for 'b'
    /* ... */
    return sign * ( q + (r==b)*(q%2) + (r<b) ); // Now 'r<b'
```

---

An earlier version of this answer did the absolute-value part with the following code:

```
    a = -a*(a<0) + a*(a>=0); // change sign of 'a' if negative
    b = -b*(b<0) + b*(b>=0); // same for 'b'
```

But that doesn't compile as well with current GCC or clang for some ISAs.  For example, GCC for x86-64 was using two CMOV instructions for each.  And clang for ARM was using a `mul` and multiple other instructions, instead of a simple `cmp` / `rsbmi reg, #0` to conditionally subtract from 0.  See it [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAGykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBm0gAOqAqETgwe3r4BpClpjgKh4VEssfGJtpj2hQxCBEzEBFk%2BfoF2mA4Z9Y0ExZExcQnSCg1NLTntY31hA2VDiQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzGHI3lgA1CbbbqP4qAB0CCfYJhoAgjt7B5jHp%2Be0eNHXt/dPjzCBEO%2BAAbsRVgx0AB9BjaLxUKhMaFpYAMBSHCBAw5MUiHbHRRbHR4mADsVkehyp%2BMEhwAju8ACI4w4AekO0ROFIe1JpwOITJZ5gArByuf9edimNEFNDotCEGIqILpRiINE2YczItxZTqdi6V5UAQUXg0YKoEx3m5DhoiSZhdhMRqTja7fbtgAxTEAWi4RJAhy4up5%2BtpquhApOzNVmOIOu23MltPleFlGHQgpdZn8QZDyeBdOhaehGcFDPMueDiYlYcLkchmZVMsj7zu22ZEAj8sVtGV1g5xfT6HQCaTdfpKMcyAA1gBPLND0sj46km1dlsCsBgaM4ls9pVj2tUisd%2BnHSz0o0m1EMQ4AKkxRYhXihF9zECLozws4XZJtRYlhmixHnqVLEJgBBrHedIhmSjL/P82Jgi%2BULQp6mBmAA8tsppogoEB8jieIEoc9rksebKskkxBAlQhHmGYIrbJm7IiugjF4riHJkfmE63haXaunaDrYOqwkgfePpMZY1YWFRhx%2BviyqYIQCBxJiDDGhyxoIES4TAEwjigpgeLVEoeYklZTxmLsyoaP8rLsmgLBJHQcQYugAhgBwwKoEkjgsHgABebwEAgaY4hiADu1S0JRVq7j6TD3kJpx2he8kpWl7aMiJiYKcgipGG8AmoMqPlMD5ymHAZRl4CZlEumePrRKlnLpfal5teJ2y5fl8lOYcCisG8/Bbhw0Q%2BYhtnmZgjnOagrnucQnmoIcsW0LQG1qYcBBxMwxALv5cRGSQCgJSqwnvN6yWHIGTBclSQ2qk1WbXSct0aoGHXyQpr0krNUJ4FQiFgURp4xpqv0KYaxp4IwwIQNFdDbbEmU%2BSZOrg9iUZnolZiihqj5MQVQ0QSwTBhFgAqXHTIKrNE9DoNu26URBUHEHeAmPoRFaXhAxDRtGhKpbBhPaplca3ISvFk%2ByShvC5bCCBisS0Kg0V05ciGkgh1nIQ1qEwug0ReAoCB4eiWLhiRKbY08FE47SsqJWeXB4rKzXMnJYOhlSIOYm7brkeOvJUm7zLJXx4fDdCkeKb74PwZRgfqtatqh5RvLe4pv3Z9SXuCn6MervrAL%2BxDKrQ6XuPVyKYo1s7wICbursPnH%2BfWZKyoQGY95406stkmH4cc9Bw1mnevP8/J/ql/BhxzTVfcDxnw9O5XvLj1zk/mo%2BsFN5Xi/L2n/OimYTK7hlI8F%2BBkETzz9IL3rS%2B0BZt/g9vD%2B70/n5S/PI%2BvIU4kj1n7AkhgZweWhGCdCmEcI22BNxAkOpN6xwDrSSGLJ2Rdy3hOPGUMG7Ey1E9Z67IKZUyhBpKgEIWB7XUg%2BEabBHx4DBHiEghwaFLUOCwBQXgNQCEOA8AASgAWUOBwh4Dx1gIH8JIO%2Bhwd4wSloRQWwsOyi0/CKSWA41F9VlqBR25ckK0hQo2GBZsLaIOIkRQkutR4Gmrjg2utICFCkJo3bkqde790HhyLOX9qRKPPAOJOx9X6nx8WvV0/jVyj2/pzGCL9mSRKfBeC%2BV8zw3zQeg4Jh9R4n3fm8T%2BeD76JJCZeMJwCwGgOMY8IaBBorrTBGmDIF1AQpkgcbGBDVrHIPtiU9Biif53iEpYdUrJJY%2BkxAAP3EmuJgrJh45n9IsZxR8QEV0NuCcxDAEZFIYH0u2wI7GgIcbSVQtd6JpTcDfDsu5eq3JApREe1IXo4jfBqRUJlhqjT3gwBRqgLQE3ktESZRJ1nxP1NczkEtMnMhvjmSsmJLlwrZlkrq/hkXqnvEC9RhDurgqJApDUmATIMDxECsshhMyLI6oyVQfpJkKMGUM6kjKfSl2qeXbllE5ovPJG89kVoaU8W%2BW8fAiI4iI3%2BYC4FikOTgprkA9BIMoCwuFJffFmd3zYtRZqw46KEWYuxW1PF9z8YKrBdqYlQ1SXkspRIlcoq6XRlRRYLgzLAlUlZWyw47rrBcupJs3l4NgmXI2TUrZtJKZhAgKgqFGCTmClJomtlNE6IQEYngJZwthRuBOWpJgs48Sm3NggPEey5oUsOBhbC2w8SYgIMQV8ohHBGBBA1JkOp80ArMNqINVJxqYmxHgQUDkCpjpidsDQ7x5J4EDZYBNCihkZsEPRRi7FWTsTzQW9J/hLjbGAI29iJ7CboDPcKC9Prz1UggM21t9UO1gkFOxHtbg%2B1mFICuoZeA8TREbTmiAXl%2BH0EWABqk0QunmLBFiUghJS1Gxg5YhAcGEOdp2a%2BGEVaDloeWBySB0DYF1oQX%2B9DOa7EqtjpszZHBli0E4MKXgfgOBaFIKgTgbhF3yQUKsdYxTbI8FIAQTQdHlgzhANsYUlwACcZhSTbH8KSDQwphSklJFwUkhN9CcEkMx0T7HOC8AUCADQwnRPLDgLAGAiAUBLTcvQMgFAIAuQc0MRoLBQSkh9PsQwwAuBcA0B7LAoIfyYAAGoI2ilhJIjBOBCZoLQfaq1KDRAM9EMIjQ5zxd4Blw6c4sLRG0J0ET3BeDK0RlhBgtBsusd4FgM2wA3BiHfjl0gWBKZGHEHV9reAIJdBMiZnrmBVCdC8PtNrQJqgGa%2BNEYgWWPBYAM82vALAcvLCoAYYAChIuYGi7FljCXZAiDEOwKQMhBCKBUOoHrugv0GCMCgbj%2BhvgmcgMsfytQhs%2BhwopFgyAkheGjGgJoI3kpcCY%2BxkyxBaJYDe/GqoNQMguChBMPwHsQizFKOUPQ%2BR0gCDR7j1I%2BOGD9Gx0MD2HQugCB6OMTwrQ9BU9qLTmYJRBjxEp9MQnnPehk/ZxIZYvG1gbAFzpjgkOWNsY4xwHExBPPeatL5jtAXLgaEuFwTEuBCAcJ2P6XgpWtAgVIOpJgNNKDick1wdXUgAAcGh/BmC4DbuT/hhSSECAxjgenSCS94NL4zpnzN1cszZiASBXMrXIJQCPjmQAedBDbnzD3/PKeC2SsLu39txbK3wOgyWTPqnS5lo6bW8tZcK8VhwbWKuCCqzVgzDWvBNZa0NoTHW/PdbY/gfrxlMBDbYyNsbE2c9Tc92x2b82jqLc2Gxlba2ysba2ztqLMXs9HcECd8Q53%2BCXaUGoAzugPbJ6e5YawL2ZTwA%2BwFNpnAfvbEUgAdRa376HsO%2B%2BX8RyV5HEBXDc6CFCPneYDnPIYnWoP/PHWoQAnHSnaoL/GnLnenHIGApHeA3nLHfnHnOnbIdHWwaYKAinQXPjEXf0MXCXAzaXWXTzRPRXZPIMUkVXdXTXfAIgKMQTRYfXCzC3GdS4SQILLgfwbYG3UkSQSQVTUkN3MXb3NbORQ9ORG3bYR3R3G3SQKQUkH3cgozWwQPA3OjUgKzWzGPOIKPFzezFaEAfzBQ9rdPDYTPVfQ7XgRLfPVLIvfLUvYvArIrEravJaFWAgOvWrLvTARrZrLaVverTATrYATverPrL/QbAzQfZAcbTYITUfGbb4SfOcafZbWiefHgRfJgbbWwg7NrHfYQUQLfaQMoq7ffW7STfQPzE/KwSwc/eHK/L7W/X7H0J/LaF/OIN/Noz/anPwH/VHRAnAzHNnIAonAoDIcA0AjIfA4ApnboBA7AxnWA4YlnJYxnNYhnTA1nOYaAwg4XM7ejRjfTHrCg1QG3fwH0ORQ4YAZAZAIMbYS4S%2BCALXFgi8bYPXIPQ3Lgm3Hg5QjQMwGTGTe3fwTTNQz3b3X3QzDgAPMzHQo3CTGQjQLTAQsEkQ/tG3eTMXMwXgNbQLMzeE/3f4sTAky4qXTQlE5YaHNIZwSQIAA).

Another way to avoid signed overflow UB is to use unsigned math in generating the abs result, like `unsigned ua = a<0 ? 0U - a : a;`.  This relies on the well-defined range-reduction semantics for conversion of negative integer types to unsigned, so is well-defined everywhere, not relying on 2's complement `int`.

---

Compilers generally make branchless asm from ternary operators when the expressions in both halves are simple and have no side-effects, but technically only the chosen side of a ternary is evaluated in the abstract machine.  (If that's a problem for more complex stuff, assign inputs to temporary variables and select between them with a ternary.)

Compilers will sometime make branchy asm from C source like `return q + ( (r==b)*(q%2) + (r>b) );`, as shown for the `bankers_div_Fe2O3` function in the Godbolt link.  (That version doesn't have sign handling; it assumes both are non-negative.)

---

**Handling of `sign` could be optimized some** if you're willing to assume 2's complement and that `>>` is an arithmetic right shift, as described in comments below.

Get `0` or `-1` from `(a^b) >> CHAR_BIT * sizeof(a)` assuming a 2's complement system and arithmetic right shift.

Alternatives include `a^b < 0 ? -1 : 0`.  Use it with a 2's complement identity bithack like you would for abs: (untested) `return mask ^ (x + mask);` which is either `~(x-1)` or `(x+0)`

Compilers do see through `((a<0)^(b<0))*-2+1` and actually compile it to `((a^b)>>31) | 1` (for 32-bit int).  But if you're assuming 2's complement, it simplifies nicely to just XORing and checking the sign bit of the result to see if they're different.

It saves one instruction to just get `0` or `-1` (leave out the OR of 1), but it costs ADD/XOR at the end instead of `imul`. So same number of total instructions, but no multiply.  This is a bigger gain on embedded systems with slow multipliers.

Comment: Branchless is probably *not* better for the full-range version handling signs, especially if you ever use it on inputs that have a predictable pattern of signs, like all positive or all negative.  It takes a lot of extra code to do this branchlessly on most ISAs, such as x86-64.  Especially with that `abs` idiom which ARM clang doesn't recognize; it actually materializes 2x 0/1 and multiplies, instead of `cmp` / `rsblt` like you'd expect from `a = a<0 ? -a : a`. https://godbolt.org/z/v4Yz7z8q5 (That has signed-overflow UB for `INT_MIN`, which you can avoid with `unsigned ua = a<0? 0U - a : a`)

Comment: The conditional negate at the end could be done with a bithack instead of a multiply, to save instructions by not materializing a -1 / +1 for `sign`.  Instead, 0 or `-1` from `(a^b) >> CHAR_BIT * sizeof(a)` assuming a 2's complement system and arithmetic right shift.  Alternatives include `a^b < 0 ? -1 : 0`.  Use it with a 2's complement identity bithack like you would for `abs`: `return mask ^ (x + mask);` which is either `~(x-1)` or `(x+0)`

Comment: Compilers do see through that `((a<0)^(b<0))*-2+1` mess and actually compile it to `((a^b)>>31) | 1` (for 32-bit int).  So that's fun.  My version saves the OR of `1`, but costs add/xor instead of imul at the end.  So same number of total instructions, but no multiply.

Comment: @PeterCordes This is why I don't write compilers. `:-)`

Comment: @PeterCordes That INT_MIN problem is always something I overlook. An easy fix has just been added to my answer. Also missing from both my answer and the one with 9 UV's is if( b == 0 ) Kaboom!... Funny what goes unnoticed...

Comment: That's a neat idea, doing `-abs(a)` (but without intermediate UB) so the result always fits.  It would still be more readable and efficient to write it as `a >= 0 ? -a : a`.  Also BTW, a more compact phrasing of "if either (not both) negative" is "if a and b have opposite signs".  Which also maps directly to the exclusive-or you're using.

Comment: I noticed at one point that answers were still dividing by `b`, but thought that seemed normal because it matches the domain of `a/b` : well-defined for every input except `b==0` and `INT_MIN/-1`.  It's not desirable for this function to do any extra checking to try to do anything that `a/b` wouldn't do for those UB cases.  It's just supposed to be a drop-in replacement for C truncating integer division.

Comment: BTW, I'm hesitant to upvote this answer mostly because of the choice to make the extra-complicated full-domain version branchless.  A branchless version would be much more appealing for dbush's first version, for non-negative `a,b` and `b < INT_MAX/2`.  And also because of the sub-optimal `-a*(a<0) + a*(a>=0)` instead of a simple and fast `a<0 ? -a : a` which I already pointed out in comments.  That pattern of multiplies looks like an anti-pattern for current compilers

Comment: (Ternaries technically only evaluate the chosen side, but when the expressions are nice and simple, free of side effects, and only use locals, compilers fairly reliably compile them to branchless code.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd welcome your taking over this particular answer to add your wisdom about "anti-pattern" and hi-IQ compilers... :-)

Comment: Look in the `#if 0` in the Godbolt link in my first comment for a more efficient version using a ternary.  All I'm asking is that you change those two `abs` lines to use ternaries.  Is there some reason you don't want to just change to what compiles more efficiently, or you want me to just make that edit instead?  BTW, compilers don't have IQ, they're just complex pieces of machinery designed by other humans.  We're pretty far from "emergent behaviour" appearing in compilers, like coming up with tricks that humans didn't teach them.  I know you didn't mean that literally, but just saying.

Comment: @PeterCordes The reason is for asking you to make an addendum (credit yourself) is that I'd be writing without firm knowledge of what you suggest. My "hello world!" was long, long ago, and I've not kept up, really... Please, be my guest... :-) (This exchange began with the Meta post about trying to have _good_ SO Q's and A's...)

Comment: Ok, if you'd rather I edit than editing yourself based on believing me that it would be more efficient, I can do that tomorrow when I have time to think if there's anything more I want to say about efficiency.  You do understand the ternary operator, though, so you can see that my suggestions is still equivalent in terms of correctness, right?

Comment: @PeterCordes Believe ? Yes() : No(); :-) I know the concept as a compact form of if/else... What modern compilers and "tentative execution" do is fascinating to me, but beyond my archaic knowledge to conceive of happening in silicon... Yes, when you have time please add your knowledge. Maybe as an addendum, though, so my version still stands as a monument to the idea us oldies aren't completely useless... :-)

Comment: Looks like it is not quite working: `mismatch: a=-1301678728 b= 2120438447 res= 0 ref= -1`

Comment: @njuffa Perhaps I should have "borrowed" the caveat from the highly UV'd answer here. "abs( b ) cannot exceed INT_MAX/2". Your finding has merit, though. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I got around to making an edit incorporating the stuff I suggested earlier in comments.

Comment: @PeterCordes Terrific! Thank you... Anyone not reading into these comments is likely to think that `I` wrote your addendum (that is well beyond my proficiencies...) Thank you for your contribution, but I invite you again to take credit (at the juncture in the answer) for the additional information provided. Happy to share credit (if it were possible.)... Again, thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Below is an ISO-C99 implementation of `divround()` that (best I can determine) is free of spurious signed integer overflow in intermediate computations. It *may* contain code that relies on the two's complement representation of signed integers. On asker's intended target architectures `int` uses a two's complement representation, so this should not be a limitation in practice.

The division first computes a preliminary integer quotient `q` and a corresponding remainder `r`. Based on the magnitude of `r` relative to the divisor `b` a correction of magnitude 1 may need to be applied to `q`, where the sign of this correction is identical to that of the mathematical quotient. The rounding to nearest-or-even is implemented via three status bits that correspond directly to the conditions of the rounding mode, as well-known from floating-point computation: a round bit, a sticky bit, and the least significant bit of the unrounded result (the truncated quotient).

The round bit and the sticky bit take a bit of care to compute. Because `r` can be as large as `b-1`, one cannot use `2*r` to check whether the fractional part of the quotient is equal to or greater than half. Instead, we need to compare the magnitude of the remainder `r` with `b/2` while taking the discarded least significant bit of the divisor `b` into account separately.

My test scaffolding below uses a x86-specific reference function. By computing in extended precision with 64 significand bits, an accurate result is computed free of double-rounding issues: Samuel A. Figueroa. "When is Double Rounding Innocuous?" *SIGNUM Newsl.*, 30(3):21–26, July 1995. Integer division typically fails and raises an exception when (1) the divisor is zero, or (2) the dividend is `INT_MIN` while the divisor is -1. My `divround()` does not check for these cases, and the test scaffolding avoids them.

The `divround()` implementation below should result in branchless code on any commonly-used compiler when compiled with full optimizations. My historical experience is that a `/`- operator and a `%`-operator sharing the same divisor do not necessarily result in a single `idiv` operation on architectures where an integer division returns both results, so where efficiency is required one would want to double check the generated assembly code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

int divround (int a, int b) 
{
    int q = a / b;
    int r = a % b;
    int abs_b_half = abs (b / 2);
    int quot_sign = ((a < 0) ^ (b < 0)) ? (-1) : 1;
    int abs_r = abs (r);
    int b_is_odd = b & 1;
    int q_is_odd = q & 1;
    int q_round  = abs_r >= (abs_b_half + b_is_odd);
    int q_sticky = b_is_odd | (abs_r != abs_b_half);
    q = q + quot_sign * (q_round & (q_sticky | q_is_odd));
    return q;
}

/* x86 specific! Computing in extended precision guarantees correct result */
int divround_ref (int a, int b) 
{
    uint16_t origcw;
    uint16_t newcw = 0x37f; // PC = extended precision, RC = to nearest or even
    int r;

    __asm fstcw  [origcw];
    __asm fldcw  [newcw];
    __asm fild   dword ptr [a];
    __asm fild   dword ptr [b];
    __asm fdivp  st(1), st;
    __asm frndint;
    __asm fistp  dword ptr [r];
    __asm fldcw  [origcw];
    
    return r;
}

// George Marsaglia's KISS PRNG, period 2**123. Newsgroup sci.math, 21 Jan 1999
// Bug fix: Greg Rose, "KISS: A Bit Too Simple" http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007
static uint32_t kiss_z=362436069, kiss_w=521288629;
static uint32_t kiss_jsr=123456789, kiss_jcong=380116160;
#define znew (kiss_z=36969*(kiss_z&65535)+(kiss_z>>16))
#define wnew (kiss_w=18000*(kiss_w&65535)+(kiss_w>>16))
#define MWC  ((znew<<16)+wnew )
#define SHR3 (kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<13),kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr>>17), \
              kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<5))
#define CONG (kiss_jcong=69069*kiss_jcong+1234567)
#define KISS ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)

int main (void)
{
    int a, b, res, ref;
    unsigned long long int c = 0;
    unsigned long long int m1 = 0x5555;
    unsigned long long int m2 = 0xaaaa;

    do {
        c++;

        a = (int)KISS;
        if ((c & m1) == m1) a = INT_MIN; // increase likelihood minimum dividend
        do {
            b = (int)KISS;
            if ((c & m2) == m2) b = INT_MIN; // incr. likelihood minimum divisor
        } while ((b == 0) ||                     // division by zero
                 ((a == INT_MIN) && (b == -1))); // integer division overflow

        res = divround (a, b);
        ref = divround_ref (a, b);
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("mismatch: a=% 11d b=% 11d res=% 11d ref=% 11d %.16f\n", a, b, res, ref, (double)a/(double)b);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if ((c & 0xffffff) == 0) printf ("\r%llx ", c);
    } while (c);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the result is non-negative (`a` and `b` have same sign, i.e. both are non-negative or both are negative), then the normally rounded division result is

```
  x = (a + b/2) / b;
```

where an exact half is rounded towards +infinity.

If the result is negative, then the normally rounded division result is:

```
  x = (a - b/2) / b;
```

where an exact half is rounded towards -infinity.

This is equal to the result of "banker's rounding" except if `x` is odd and the rounding was from an exact half. An exact half is obtained if "a/b=x-½" or equivalently, "b * x = a + b/2" (in the "non-negative" case) or "b * x = a - b/2" (in the "negative" case) and if that happens, then `x` must be decremented/incremented by 1 to get the correct result.

Notice that if `b` is odd, then with `a` and `b` being integers, it is not possible for "a/b" to have a fractional part of exactly ½. So the intermediate result only may need correction if `b` is even and in that case, the conditions above involve only integer terms.

All in all, we have:

```
int divround(int a, int b)
{
    int x;
    if((a<0) == (b<0))
    {   // a and b have same sign
        x = (a + b/2) / b;
        if((b%2 == 0) && (x%2 != 0) && (b*x == a + b/2))  // b even, x odd and a/b=x-1/2
        {
            x--;
        }
    }
    else
    {   // a and b have different sign
        x = (a - b/2) / b;
        if((b%2 == 0) && (x%2 != 0) && (b*x == a - b/2))  // b even, x odd and a/b=x+1/2
        {
            x++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Of course, if `a` and `b` are assumed to be non-negative, then only the first case in the `if`-`else`-statement is needed.

A few test cases:

```
divround(3, 2) == 2
divround(-3, 2) == -2
divround(3, -2) == -2
divround(-3, -2) == 2
divround(5, 2) == 2
divround(-5, 2) == -2
divround(5, -2) == -2
divround(-5, -2) == 2
divround(5, 1) == 5
divround(5, -1) == -5
divround(5, 3) == 2
divround(5, -3) == -2
divround(0, 2) == 0
divround(0, -2) == 0
```

Note: this solution relies on `a+b/2` and `a-b/2` to not overflow or underflow, so do not walk too close to the edge.

Comment: @njuffa Right, I have added a note about this. I did not consider overflow when writing this, my purpose was primarily to handle negatives (which no other answer did at that time) and an alternative formula that might be easier to understand for some people. In any case, thank you for your observation.

Answer (score 0):

For `b>0` and any `a`, the following works:

```
return (a+(b/2) - (~(b|a/b) &1))/ b
```

Logic:

- Do normal rounding: `(a+(b/2))/b`
- If b is even `~b&1` AND a/b is even `~(a/b)&1`, (put together: `(~(b|a/b) &1)` ), round down

Comment: Not quite any `a`; this has signed overflow for large `a` and `b`, like for `INT_MAX / 100`, doing `INT_MAX + 50` has signed overflow UB.  You could use `unsigned` to avoid this if your inputs are known non-negative.

Comment: For efficiency, this divides twice, so it's probably not as efficient as branching except with constant `b`, especially on embedded CPUs (cheaper branching, slower integer dividers than Ice Lake or Zen).  Even on modern x86, it can be worth avoiding an extra `div` or `idiv` instruction.